# Does an adapter for a flat mount caliper to post mount fork exist?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a CAAD12 disc which I'd like to fit SRAM Force 22 hydraulic to. I've been a bit enthusiastic buying things without really researching all the pitfalls of the different bits and bobs that go into disc brakes and compatibility thereof.

So, it turns out that the CAAD12 fork is post mount, but my calipers are flat mount. Is there an adapter to fit a flat mount caliper to a post mount fork?

Comment: But researching bike purchases is one of the fun parts!

Comment: Haha, yes, I just wanted to get riding though. Looks like I'm gonna give Ultegra a go. I hear its quite popular...

Comment: https://www.competitivecyclist.com/shimano-flat-mount-disc-brake-adapter?ti=OjoxOjM6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [bikehugger.com](https://www.bikehugger.com/posts/road-disc-brake-tech-flat-mount-vs-post-mount)

> What about fitting flat-mount calipers to post-mount framesets? Think again. No such adapters exist, and if I were you I wouldn’t hold my breath waiting for them to appear. It’s probably not geometrically possible.

Sounds like from that site that it's pretty much not even possible to get it working. Best option might be to sell your old calipers and get some new ones or see if anybody in your area is looking for a trade.

Comment: Fortunately they're still unused, I have the receipt so I can just return them.

Answer (score -3):

Yes adapters do exist in the aftermarket. But there are advantages and disadvantages

The pros include

- You get to use the brake you want on the bike you want
- other...

The cons include

- You need to have another layer between your brake and your frame, which is another source of possible flex and loss of rigidity
- Some additional Weight to carry around
- Clearance may become an issue depending on lots of factors
- other ...

Example of an adapter:

[image: From https://www.assolutions.ca/]
 <sup>from  https://www.assolutions.ca/</sup>

Comment: Please take a moment to read the [tour] and how the site works.  Answers should be self-contained and not depend on external sites that can change and vanish.  You must  state if you have any association with the item/site/etc   and to be honest that address looks dodgy as heck.  Without prior knowledge, I would assume you're being "funny".   I'll have a go at editing this, but you'll need to complete it.

Comment: I have used these adapters to successfully run Shimano 105 BR-7070 brakes on my post-mount fork and frame.